# How can I set a video default image with Kaltura Player without using the KMC?

Tags: video, kaltura

Or, How can I set the default image for a video without editing the Media Entry?

I want to specify a specific video second for a thumbnail, or provide my own URL within the HTML.  By providing the player a url like:

`https://cdnsecakmi.kaltura.com/p/1475532/sp/147553200/thumbnail/entry_id/1_alg5s8io/vid_sec/12`

And then being able to dynamically set the `vid_sec`:

`https://cdnsecakmi.kaltura.com/p/1475532/sp/147553200/thumbnail/entry_id/1_alg5s8io/vid_sec/${VID_SEC}`

---

Normally, one would set what Kaltura calls 'Default Thumbnail' through the KMC,

By either the gui:  Content->Entries->(edit entry)->Thumbnails->Add Thumbnail

Or by API call: https://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/index.php?service=media&action=updatethumbnail

But both of these methods involve editing the Media Entry on the server.

I need to be able to set the image shown before the play button is pressed within the flashvars, javascript, or html so I can maintain it in a template instead of on the KMC.

I've tried setting:

`<span itemprop="thumbnail" content="(thumbnail url)"></span>`

which doesn't seem to work.

I've also put both 'thumbnailURL' and 'thumbnail' within flashvars, and that didn't do it either.

```
kWidget.embed({
  "targetId": "kaltura_player_1413399902",
  "wid": "_XXXX",
  "uiconf_id": xxxxxxx,
  "flashvars": {'thumbnailUrl': "URL OF THUMBNAIL"},
  "cache_st": 1413399902,
  "entry_id": "1_XXXXXXXX"
});
```

Comment: Is the image file in the same domain?  Did you open 'Developer Tools' in your browser to see what happens to the image file request (is the request ignored, or does it fail with a return code?)  Can you share that with us?

Comment: The image I provide is not present in the request, but very good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added to the latest version thumbnailUrl param which you can define on your embed code.

```
  kWidget.embed({
  "targetId": "kaltura_player",
  "wid": "_1281471",
  "uiconf_id": 27119341,
  "flashvars": {
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Double-alaskan-rainbow.jpg"
  },
  "cache_st": 1416828471,
  "entry_id": "1_d5o9twuk"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itayKinnrot/0wpnhawt/ <-- Exmaple

Comment: Note that I did have to go into the KMC and select 'update player' on the universal studio tab before it began working:  as in "Use The Latest Version".  Thanks!